# How to open a tab automatically when coming from a other site?

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment I have a site with a table of elements. These elements have some sub-elements. And i have a second site where i can see the element and many tabs for the sub-elements. 
The im calling the site at the moment that way:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" role="presentation" asp-controller="Scenario" asp-action="SimulationEvaluation">Auswerten</a>
```

So the element is a Simulation and the sub-elements are results of the simulation. 
The tabs and the function in the second page look like this:

```
<div class="tab" style=" border: none; overflow:hidden">
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Ergebnis-1')" id="defaultOpen">Ergebnis-1</button>
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Ergebnis-2')">Ergebnis-2</button>
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Ergebnis-3')">Ergebnis-3</button>
            </div>

<div id="Ergebnis-1" class="tabcontent">
    ......
</div>
<div id="Ergebnis-2" class="tabcontent">
    ......
</div>
<div id="Ergebnis-3" class="tabcontent">
    ......
</div>

<script>

    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

    function openTab(evt, name) {
        // Declare all variables
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

        // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
        document.getElementById(name).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

My question is now: When i click on a subelement in the table of the first page, i want so get the matching tab opened automatically. So when I click on Simulation-1, Result-3 for Example, i want the Result-3-Tab pre-opened. Is that possible? ^^

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can send parameters via query params and on the second site read those params inside javascript

Comment: Could you tell me how? I've never worked with javascript and only copied the function from a html site :D

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want. You want to open thing in a new tab ? It's easily done : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp. If I understand correctly you also want to focus the opened tab. It will depend on your browser. With Chrome the link I share with you will work... But if you want to focus an old tab (opened 3 min ago by example) it will not work and it will open/focus a new tab.

Comment: Not exactly ^^ I want a html tab, no a new Tab in my browser. The tabs are existing already, i just want to select the matching tab for the subelement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first site you have to set up links like this

```
<a href="secondsite.com?tab=Simulation-1">Simulation-1</a>
<a href="secondsite.com?tab=Result-3">Result-3</a>
```

And in the second website you have to add this javascript code inside document.ready:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const tabName = urlParams.get('tab');

if (tabName){
 document.querySelector('[onclick*=' + tabName + ']').click();
}
```